# Changing watcher value in watcher

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have some code similar to below:

```
<some_component v-model="some_value" />
{{ some_value }}
```

In my script code I have the following:

```
 ...
 data() {
     return {
         some_value: 'initial'
     };
 },
 ...
 watch: {
     some_value(new_value, old_value) {
         // Small subset of code, actual code does much more than this
         if (new_value === 'some_new_value') {
              this.some_value = 'can not use that value';
         }
     }
 },
 ...
```

So everything seems be functioning fine, until I try to change the value I'm watching from within the watcher itself.  I would expect the watcher to fire again, but it doesn't and although value of the `v-model` changes, it does't change in the UI.

I tried using `this.$forceUpdate()` before and after change but it didn't seem to work.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Also, is your component paying attention to changes in the value after initialization?

Comment: Okay, code is corrected.  No, I do not have immediate flag set on watch.  Does the immediate flag mean when the value has "changed" or the component has started and the watcher "starts"?  The documentation isn't very clear on it's lifecycle.

Comment: That's not quite what I am asking. Can you post the component code? I cannot reproduce your problem. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/zEbOeX?editors=1010

Comment: Is there a problem with just using `v-bind` and `@input` instead of `v-model`? In @input you could call a method with the logic you're trying to include in the watcher. I think it's better not changing the value in a watcher. EDIT: Never mind, just saw Bert's pen.

Comment: Bert's pen is exactly what we're doing.  The parent component takes the value and basically puts it in a `v-model` of an `input` within the component itself.

Comment: There seems to be an issue somewhere outside of what is shown in the question. Can you put together an example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Sean bret's codepen shows the output that you are expecting, right?

Comment: Yes.  I got around it doing a different method unrelated to the problem here.  But nevertheless, could not get the value I'm watching to update within the watch.  I'm chalking it up to an issue with component itself.

Answer (score 10):

You shouldn't update the value you're watching in its watcher, but if you have no other choice you can use `$nextTick`

```js
some_value(new_value, old_value) {
  // Small subset of code, actual code does much more than this
  if (new_value === 'some_new_value') {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.some_value = 'can not use that value';
    })
  }
}
```

another way to do it (and the best in my opinion) is directly overriding `v-model`.
as you may know, `v-model="some_value"` is shorthand for `:value="some_value"` and `@input="some_value=$event"`. so you can do what you're trying to like this:

```html
<some-component
  :value="some_value" 
  @input="some_value=some_method($event)"
/>
```

Comment: This is a great technique when you need to filter an input value before setting the value of a ref or triggering reactivity.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is in this situation with Vue3 + script setup, a solution would be the "update:modelValue":

```html
<some-component
  v-model="some_value"
  @update:modelValue="set_some_value"
/>
```